# Null Reference Exception , But it is NOT a null value

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller

I yesterday started working on my first .NET c# MVC project.
Now I receive a null reference when i try to POST but before that when i try to read from that same value it works fine.
What I mean is that when the page loads, it loads the value correctly, but when i press the submit button it throws the exception .

```
@model QnA_WebApp_MVC.Models.Block
@{
    Block block = (Block)@TempData["block"];
}
<h5>User: @block.user_id</h5>
```

And the thing is that the block.user_id is not even among the posted values.

Comment: I assume when you load the page, it's a `GET` request, and when you submit, it goes through the `POST` or similar route where you didn't set `block` value in your `TempData`?

Comment: In the controller script in the function that returns View() for this page i have "this.TempData["block"] = block;" before the return. In the view cshtml file I have what I posted above

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Anyway I found the solution my self. I changed the

```
Block block = (Block)@TempData["block"];
```

To

```
Block block = new Block();
block = ViewBag.block;
```

In a previous attempt i had tried

```
Block block = ViewBag.block;
```

and it was not working -> null reference exception

I believe that the solution was that i first declared the block as a new Block() but i am not 100%. Anyway now it works so i am moving on